# How to bulk edit image url in featured image and product description?

Tags: permalinks, urls, site-url, wp-update-post

I have tried a few plugins (free) but none update the url in featured product image and product descriptions.

How can I update in bulk instead of doing one by one? If there any any plugin (preferably free) that can edit the image url, please let me know.

Thanks